# Google Forms submitting to Google Sheets - Creating a "Dashboard"

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I currently have a task request Google Forms submitting tasks into a Google Sheets. I'd like to use that sheet as a database for a 'Front End' that allows me to select a status for a project (this would be a new field).

Is this possible to do right in a tab on the same sheet?

Or would it be better to do through HTML/API combo?

Comment: Just a note: While someone might recommend an app which will solve your question, questions _requesting_ app recommendations are off-topic. I suggest removing that part of your question and focusing on the problem you're trying to solve. You may also find this helpful: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely create a new tab.   I just created an example setup for something like this [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gFtUSVPcEn3hkRyry0eOjpc-MJxui6gZF-TN85NtYS4/edit?usp=sharing)

I use a new sheet (Sheet2) that contains extra fields as well as the original data imported through a =query statement in Task2!B1

The query is very simple: `=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:Z, "select A,B")` - add more than A,B if you are adding more columns (and if you're adding way more columns, you will probably want to replace Z with something larger.)

It is possible you could even insert the extra column directly in the Form Responses sheet; I've not tried what happens if you add columns there.